# blockquote quotes style

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a blockquote style where the opening and closing quotes are bigger than the  text but still fit on its line, something like this [image: example]

this is the code I have http://jsfiddle.net/EnL3R/2/

```
<div id="conteudo">
  <ul class="parcerias">
    <li><a href="#">Title- <i>Author</i></a></li>
     <li class="descricao">
        <blockquote>
            
            <p><span>“</span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus fringilla nisl quis enim scelerisque ac consectetur tortor molestie. Morbi mollis augue et risus imperdiet dictum. Suspendisse sed sapien nec erat pretium consectetur et et metus. Maecenas tincidunt turpis placerat nisi vulputate at volutpat ante vulputate. Duis accumsan suscipit posuere. Nunc suscipit facilisis dapibus. Nulla scelerisque felis sed urna bibendum facilisis. Vivamus fermentum egestas lorem ac accumsan. Aenean vulputate massa pharetra sapien tincidunt placerat. Aenean molestie luctus velit. Ut cursus ante ante, quis luctus diam. Ut varius, lorem non vestibulum ornare, sem nisi gravida leo, a molestie mauris mauris non orci. Proin sit amet leo nunc.
            </p> 
            <p> 
            Nunc mollis, nunc eu vestibulum feugiat, lacus dui hendrerit metus, a placerat nulla tortor eget lacus. Etiam semper ligula turpis. Vivamus eget luctus nulla. Aliquam non nibh turpis. Aliquam aliquet lorem id massa cursus auctor egestas est tempor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus at purus vitae tortor venenatis vulputate eget eu metus. Donec accumsan metus scelerisque orci iaculis sed hendrerit ante suscipit. Vivamus tortor dolor, varius mollis scelerisque sed, sollicitudin a tellus. Mauris sit amet tincidunt mauris. Sed sed massa arcu, non eleifend felis. Cras non lacus nisi. Nulla magna turpis, lobortis ac adipiscing sed, consequat sed augue.
            </p> 
            <p> 
            Donec vel purus tortor, ut viverra mauris. Vivamus urna sapien, eleifend at posuere a, malesuada nec risus. In vitae erat in mauris ornare iaculis. Phasellus consectetur vestibulum risus non facilisis. Ut eu nibh quam. Donec eu augue sit amet lacus feugiat ullamcorper eu bibendum arcu. Pellentesque elementum rutrum nisi, ut pellentesque est bibendum id. Fusce justo lacus, venenatis eu vehicula a, porttitor quis mi.
            </p> 
            <p> 
            Sed in felis urna, non vestibulum magna. Nullam vitae augue sed mauris fermentum facilisis. Sed dictum diam eget ante varius at rhoncus arcu rutrum. Suspendisse lorem neque, convallis a vehicula quis, faucibus faucibus elit. Sed eget mauris nec felis malesuada pharetra quis in eros. Fusce urna nisi, iaculis vitae blandit non, posuere et nulla. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aenean vel leo sem. Vestibulum posuere, neque non mollis laoreet, quam quam pretium elit, in tincidunt lacus lectus ac lorem. Mauris vel odio dolor. Phasellus faucibus lobortis justo id malesuada.
            </p> 
            <p> 
            Nullam sed dolor id purus feugiat tincidunt. Aliquam eget consequat lacus. Cras augue erat, mattis sed consequat eget, mattis vel tellus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut in ornare lorem. Nam quis sodales tellus. Sed consequat imperdiet mattis. Morbi quis odio quis massa pellentesque laoreet. Curabitur lacinia lacus risus. Maecenas tincidunt ullamcorper ultrices.<span class="ultimo">„</span>
                       </p> 
            
        </blockquote>    
    </li>
```

```
/* CSS Document */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LoraBold';
    src: url('fonts/lora-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/lora-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/lora-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/lora-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/lora-bold-webfont.svg#LoraBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'LoraItalic';
    src: url('fonts/lora-italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/lora-italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/lora-italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/lora-italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/lora-italic-webfont.svg#LoraItalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'LoraRegular';
    src: url('fonts/lora-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/lora-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/lora-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/lora-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/lora-regular-webfont.svg#LoraRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}



#conteudo ul.parcerias li.descricao blockquote {
    font-style:italic;
    margin:2em 0 3em 2em;
    quotes:'”' '„';
    
}


#conteudo ul.parcerias li.descricao blockquote span {
    font-size:1000%;
    color:black;
    display:inline;
    }

#conteudo ul.parcerias li.descricao blockquote span.ultimo {
    float:none;
    font-size:1000%;
    color:black;
    display:inline;
}
```

the open quote shows above the text, and both the open and closing quotes put some margins on it, I realize that it's because the character in the font itself has this white space, is there anyway I can compensate this?

Comment: I edited the post , hope it's clear now

Comment: Pseudo-elements :before & :after seems to be a better approach: http://jsfiddle.net/EnL3R/12/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modified `padding`, `margin`, `display` and `position` attributes and now it seem to be displayed ok:

```css
blockquote span {
    font-size:100px;
    color:black;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0px;
}

blockquote span.primo {
    margin: -40px 0 -100px 0;
    bottom: -40px;
}

blockquote span.ultimo {
    margin:-130px 0 0 0;
    bottom:0px;
}

/* IE7 only styles */
blockquote span {
    *display: inline; zoom: 1; /* IE7 fix for inline-block */
}
blockquote span.primo {
    *margin: -20px; *bottom: -20px; /* IE7 position adjustment */
}
blockquote span.ultimo {
    *margin: -50px; /* IE7 position adjustment */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EnL3R/26/ (that yellow border around the `span` tag is only for testing)

Comment: +1 - this solution looks the easiest without fiddling with images + works even on older browsers

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have to worry about displaying in ie7 or older, I think pseudo elements would be the way to go. http://jsfiddle.net/EnL3R/16/

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like you might be better off using images.  If you try and use text for the quotation marks, you run up against the fact that the quotation mark itself is only a small portion of the line height.

You can just put the images in your content and use `vertical-align` to get the positioning right. If you don't need support for IE 7 or below, you can even put them in the CSS, in the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements.

```
blockquote :first-child:before {
    content: url('images/openquote.png');
    }

 blockquote :last-child:after {
    content: url('images/closequote.png');
    vertical-align: -35px; /* tuned to fit image */
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EnL3R/17/

Comment: If you're using pseudo elements to display the quotes, no reason to use images instead of text. You can position the pseudo elements any way you want. That would also cut down on http requests. Or at the very least, use a css sprite.

Comment: True - I guess I just don't like tuning the negative margins to fight against the extra whitespace, just for the sake of using the quotation marks from the font directly.  It feels like you're after a very specific visual effect, and images seem conceptually more suited to that than using CSS to extract and render two individual glyphs from your font in a way that is clearly separate from the surrounding text.

Comment: The point about HTTP requests is a good one - if you're worried about it, you could use `data:` URIs to get everything in a single request, as the images are going to be pretty small.

Answer (score -1):

Update the style of blockquote.. check below code for it.

```
blockquote {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding:20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
blockquote:before {
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    content: "\201C";
}
blockquote:after {
   top:80px;
   content: "\201D";
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #dd7975;
}
```

Comment: Based on the domain/URL of your link(s) being the same as, or containing, your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you *must disclose that it's your site*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).

Comment: When you copy from somewhere else, the [referencing requirements for Stack Exchange](/help/referencing) must be met (i.e. state it's a copy; state the original author and source; and use quote formatting to indicate what portions you are copying).